# Resetting specific timeout based on an id

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to call a method that posts an answer after an input change. To avoid several posts i tried to reset that timeout if another input change has happened. Is there any smart way of doing this?

This is for an angular project that posts answers for multiple different questions. So i need to make sure the code doesnt cancel the wrong timeout

```js
var calls = {};
function postAnswer(answer) {
    if(calls[answer.id]) {
        clearTimeout(calls[answer.id]);
        console.log('cleared ' + answer.id);
    }
    calls[answer.id] = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("posted " + answer.id)
        delete calls[answer.id];
    }, 2000)
}
```

There might be some sort of method i dont know of. For example in RxJS or somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use de-bouncing here. In rxJs debouncing operator is useful to do same in angular. debounceTime(2000). So, whenever user stops typing after 2000-ms events got fired. this is statckblitz link can help you.. [DebounceDemo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-adheqt?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=50)

Comment: Is this also useable if theres different answer types. ie Select, radiobuttons and so on?

Comment: And i also have an N amount of questions so not sure if this is the way

Comment: You can if that is your use-case.

Comment: Look this https://jsitor.com/SpvvgAwsu . In here, button clicked multiple times but after 500 result of counter is implemented. This is your customize debounce function.

Comment: I might be asking stupid questions here - but how do i add eventlisteners for an x amount of "questions"(Dont know how many) which can have different answertypes (select, radiobuttongroup, etc.)

Im using a ngFor* to show questions and a ngSwitch* to change the answer types. The answer is always the same though (between 0 and 5)

Comment: In this case, you need to share your problem in stackblitz. so other can understand it properly what you want to do.